# CS50 filter-more edges

Tags: c, cs50

The below code is for the edges filter-more problem from CS50 Problem Set 4. It first copies the RGBTRIPLE of the image into a temporary file, and loops through every pixel, and then through every pixel around it.

```c
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    long gxRed, gxGreen, gxBlue, gyRed, gyGreen, gyBlue;
    int row_x, row_y, column_x, column_y, a, b;
    int gx_arr[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int gy_arr[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            gxRed = 0;
            gxGreen = 0;
            gxBlue = 0;
            gyRed = 0;
            gyGreen = 0;
            gyBlue = 0;

            for (a = i - 1, row_x = 0, row_y = 0; a <= i + 1; a++, row_x++, row_y++)
            {
                for (b = j - 1, column_x = 0, column_y = 0; b <= j + 1; b++, column_x++, column_y++)
                {
                    if (a < 0 || b < 0 || a > height || b > width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    gxRed += image[a][b].rgbtRed * gx_arr[row_x][column_x];
                    gxGreen += image[a][b].rgbtGreen * gx_arr[row_x][column_x];
                    gxBlue += image[a][b].rgbtBlue * gx_arr[row_x][column_x];

                    gyRed += image[a][b].rgbtRed * gy_arr[row_y][column_y];
                    gyGreen += image[a][b].rgbtGreen * gy_arr[row_y][column_y];
                    gyBlue += image[a][b].rgbtBlue * gy_arr[row_y][column_y];
                }
                column_x = 0;
                column_y = 0;
            }

            copy[i][j].rgbtRed   = fmin(round(sqrt(gxRed * gxRed + gyRed * gyRed)), 255);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = fmin(round(sqrt(gxGreen * gxGreen + gyGreen * gyGreen)), 255);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue  = fmin(round(sqrt(gxBlue * gxBlue + gyBlue * gyBlue)), 255);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i
][j] = copy[i][j];
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Full results of CS50:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. The failed test cases provide you with the test data that was used. This is a good time to start looking into using a debugger. You should provide the same data (as a hardcoded array)  to your function and step through your code in a debugger. Then you can check all variables and see if they hold the values you expect.

Comment: In your loops, `column_x` and `column_y` will always hold the same value. Same for `row_x` and `row_y`. It doesn't make any sense to use 2 variables if they never hold different values. You can simplify your loops accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you overrun the bounds of the arrays when processing pixels at the edges of the image.  For instance, when `i` and `j` are 0, `a` and `b` both start at -1, and you access members of `image[a][b]`.

Comment: `if (a < 0 || b < 0 || a > height || b > width)` That should be `>=` for the upper limits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are right about the array bounds, but the cases where `i` or `j` are `0` would be avoided by `continue;` It is the upper end of the range that causes pain.